# Making Advice PRV-850 quiet

Tags: ups

I've recently bought the Advice PRV-850 UPS. It works as expected, but when there's a power drop, it constantly beeps and I don't know how to make it quiet.

I had a different model of the Advice UPS before, and I could stop the beeping by clicking the only button on it. With this one, clicking on the only button it has turns it off, along with the PC and everything else.

Is there any solution for this, or is it by design? It's not a grave issue, but it can be quite annoying at times.

Comment: What does the manual say about muting the alerm?  Did you install the communications cable and the agent software?  If not, install those and look in the software for mute button and options and perhaps input tolerance levels so that it doesn't alarm as easily when the power sags.

Comment: I didn't find the relevant section in the manual. As for the software - I never had the need to install it, and I thought the beeping is a hardware thing. Could it be that the only way to mute it is by using the software?

Comment: I've run into several models of UPS that can only be silenced via the software. It's lame, but that's the way it goes sometimes. :)

Comment: I've contacted their support, they said it's not possible to turn off the beeping. Thanks for your help, anyway.